# IIS7 - URL Rewrite issue

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite some urls and i've done this in the past but for some reason it just won't stick this time. Here's the rule:

```
    <rule name="Force HTTPS - Test.aspx" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                            <match url="^Templates/Test\.aspx" />
                            <conditions>
                                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^my\.domain\.com$" />
                                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                            </conditions>
                            <action type="Redirect" url="https://my.domain.com/Templates/test.aspx" />  
</rule>
```

It should be taking http://my.domain.com/Templates/test.aspx and redirecting to **https**://my.domain.com/Templates/test.aspx.

Unfortunately it's not working at all, no matter what i try....

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that IIS was configured to force SSL on the files I tried redirecting. That meant it would return an HTTP 403 error before even checking the url rewrite rules.

Hope that helps someone else.